# ディレクトリ内のファイルを一括移動

Tags: linux

特定のファイル拡張子を持つディレクトリ内の何千ものファイルを別のディレクトリに移動することは可能ですか？たとえば、.cppディレクトリと.hppディレクトリがあります。 .cppディレクトリ内のすべての.hppファイルを.hppディレクトリに移動します。 `mv ** / *。hpp / path / to / single / target / directory`を使おうとすると、それほど多くのファイルを扱うことができないと言われます。

Answer (score 3):

`find` コマンドの `-exec` オプションが使えます。ただしサブディレクトリへ移動しようとしている場合の挙動は自明ではないのでご注意ください。

```
find <探索元ディレクトリ> -type f -name "*.hpp" -exec mv {} <移動先ディレクトリ> \;
```

または GNU 版の mv だと下のようにも書けます。

```
find <探索元ディレクトリ> -type f -name "*.hpp" -exec mv --target-directory=<移動先ディレクトリ> {} +
```

Comment: 端末は、私に各ファイルを個別に見てもらうよう要求しています と find <探索元ディレクトリ> -type f -name "*.hpp" -exec mv {} <移動先ディレクトリ> \;

Comment: @CodyRutscher Unfortunately, I can't understand what you want to say....

Answer (score 0):

```
find cpp -name "*.hpp" -print | xargs -I@ mv @ hpp
```

Comment: あまりないシチュエーションですが、`-print` と `-I` を使うやり方だとファイル名に改行文字が含まれる場合に上手く動きません。`-print` の代わりに `-print0` を使い xargs で `-0` を使う回避策があります。または[私の回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/52802/19110)のように `-exec` を使うのもアリです。