# find -name *png の結果をディレクトリにまとめる

Tags: linux, shellscript

Linuxの　find -name *png の出力が、大量にある場合
同一ディレクトリのものを、一つにまとめディレクトリのみにまとめる
こんなシェルスクリプトは可能でしょうか？

Comment: 重複候補([回答あり](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/52802/3060)) - [ディレクトリ内のファイルを一括移動](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/52800/3060)

Comment: 「複数ディレクトリのものを一つにまとめる」ならわかるのですが、「同一ディレクトリのもの」とはどういう状況でしょうか？ それとも質問文の誤りでしょうか？

Comment: 簡単なサンプル例（こんなファイル一覧があって、このディレクトリに移動したい）を示してもらうと意図が伝わりやすくなると思います。

Comment: .pngファイルが１つのディレクトリ内に複数あるので、wc すると17602行もありました。そこで１ディレクトリ１行にしたいのです

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ディレクトリ内の該当ファイルのファイル名の長さに左右されますが下記のようにすると良さそうです。

```
find -name "*png" -execdir sh -c 'echo $PWD' _ {} \+
```

それでも重複するようなら下記のようにパイプでつないで`uniq`すればより確実だと思います。

```
find -name "*png" -execdir sh -c 'echo $PWD' _ {} \+ | uniq
```

Answer (score 0):

自己解決

```
find -name *png > file1
cat file1 | sed 's:\(.*\)/.*:\1:' > file2
uniq file2 file3
```

で、出来ました。